# Possibility to delete unused data of growing website in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, website, embedded-linux

I’m new here and was searching for an article, what say how to delete unused data.
I have a website running on an embedded Linux device. It shows basically the whole time the same content, but grows until the memory is full.
In other Web browsers this behave isn’t. Does someone have an idea how to delete the old/unused/whatever data in chrome automatically?
My system is running in fullscreen, without info- and toolbar. It is no option that the user clears the cache by hand.

Is there maybe a start option for chrome?

Thanks for your help. And I hope, I did this question in the right way.